# expressjs serve static content with path parameter

Tags: node.js, express

Using expressjs to server create react app after build.

[image]

Works perfectly fine with below line in server.js;

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));`

So, `http://localhost:3001/` works OK.

I need to use the app like `http://localhost:3001/ssh`

So, updated server.js like;

`app.use("/ssh", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));`

However, when I tried to browse `http://localhost:3001/ssh/` below error happens;

[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app structure is not correct. You have to use a router to build your endpoints.

```
- server.js
const router = require(./public/router);
app.use('/', router);

- router.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use("/ssh", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build"));
module.exports = router;
```

Create a `router.js` under public folder and import that router in your `server.js`

Comment: no need to create a extra file. can be done on server.js

Comment: tried as below together with `homepage="/ssh"`, but  http://localhost:3001/ssh/  still getting the same errors.

am I using the router wrong way?

`const app = express();`
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/ssh", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.use("/",router);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one fix to do. just add  `"homepage": "/ssh"` to your package.json file, what ever front-end framework you are using. Then re-build. it should work fine then.

[image]

Thanks.